# applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification) does not execute in AppleScript

Tags: xcode, cocoa, applescript-objc

In summary: Using AppleScript-objc and Xcode. `applicationWillFinishLaunching_` in one project executes but in another project with identical code it does not execute.

In my main project I want to test for and create a plist file to hold default values for the program.  I tested the code in another simple project with just test code in it and the code worked properly.  In the main program, with the code copied and pasted, it did not execute although the program ran normally in all other ways.

I commented out the plist code and inserted a tell finder-choose file-end tell in both projects.  Again this worked in the test file but not in the main project.  In the test file the choose window appeared then when dismissed, the normal window appeared.

I have searched here and using a wider Google search but have not found anything relevant except for one question here that was resolved by fixing a problem caused by another program not loading.  I am not loading anything other than my project.  Also, the main.m and the top of the app delegate script in both my project files are identical.

Any suggestions as to what to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the project settings identical?

Answer (score 0):

After more poking around I found the following:  **The connection between the File Owner and the Delegate was missing.**  I probably removed it without realizing I did so.

Another indication that this had happened appeared some time early on in setting up the interface and that was that the Delegate cube name changed to "App Delegate" as shown in the popup label when hovering the cursor over it.  "App Delegate" also appeared in the Bindings and Connections panels.  It did not appear to have any impact on the program until I added code to the ..willFinishLaunching handler.